# How to collect a 2D array in java 8 from a list of objects

Tags: java-8

I needs a way to collect to a 2D array from a list of objects. Each 1-D array would be of size 2, which would be taken from the Pair object.

```
class Pair {
public int start;
public int end;
public Pair(int start, int end) {
    this.start = start;
    this.end = end;
}
public boolean contains(Pair pair) {
    return this.end >= pair.start;
}
public int[][] convert(List<Pair> listOfPair) {
    int[][] result = listOfPair.stream().map(x -> new int[] {x.start, x.end}).collect(**??**)
}
```

}

I need a way for my convert method above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the arrays to a List and then convert that to an array:

```
return listOfPair.stream().map(x -> new int[]{x.start,
                    x.end}).collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new int[0][0]);
```

This just collects the 2 element arrays into a list, and then converts the List to an array.

The `toArray` function allocates a new array with the type of its parameter (int[][] in this case) and copies the data from the list into it. The `new int[0][0]` gives a type to `Array.newInstance()` to allow it to create an array of the desired type.

As you know the size of the array at the start, you could do this, which has only one memory allocation:

```
public static int[][] convert2(List<Pair> listOfPair) {
    int[][] result = new int[listOfPair.size()][2];
    int i = 0;
    for (Pair p : listOfPair) {
        result[i][0] = p.start;
        result[i++][1] = p.end;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What does .toArray(new int[0][0]) perform?